# React Native Firebase: how to check authorization?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

After calling "createUserWithEmailAndPassword" or "signInWithEmailAndPassword", a property "currentUser" becomes filled in "auth()". It remains full after restarting an application, even if I remove this user from the Firebase console.

How can I check user's authorization when the application starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force the client to "check in" with the server, you would use the [`User#getIdToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) method by calling `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)`. If the user has been deleted, this should reject with the error code `'auth/user-token-expired'`.

From the [React Native Firebase Quick Start documentation](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/auth/quick-start#subscribe-to-auth-state-changes), I'll use this as the base of the MWE:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

function App() {
  // Set an initializing state whilst Firebase connects
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  // Handle user state changes
  function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

  if (initializing) return null;

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Login</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Welcome {user.email}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Once the user has logged in or their cached access has been restored, `onAuthStateChanged` will receive an event with the current user object. Here we add the ID token request.

```js
function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
  if (!user) {
    // not logged in
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
    return;
  }

  user.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true)
    .then(token => {
      // if here, this user is still authorised.
      setUser(user);
      if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
    }, error => {
      if (error.code === 'auth/user-token-expired') {
        // token invalidated. No action required as onAuthStateChanged will be fired again with null
      } else {
        console.error('Unexpected error: ' + error.code);
      }
    });
}
```